# getting all nodes having a styleClass in the scene graph

Tags: css, javafx, scenegraph

I want to define a global search in my program. My program has many nodes in a scene and there are a lot of common things on different nodes that could be searched. I think of defining a class searchable and a method for searching in each node.

So when I search by a class selector I would be able to reach all the nodes to highlight them for the user.

For example if Scene or Node has a method like this:

```
scene.getBySelector(".searchable").filter( (p)-> (Searchable)p.search()).forEach((p) -> (Searchable)p.setHighlited());
```

It is certainly can be done by iterating a scene or node children recursively but it looks to me so heavy so I'd like to know if there exists such a thig:

```
CSSUtils.getBySelector(".searchable").filter((p) -> p.getScene() == myScene)...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Node` has methods [`lookup(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) and [`lookupAll(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) which I think are what you are looking for.